# Намертво зависает VS 2017, если комментарий перед функцией слишком длинный

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

У меня установлена VS 2017 Community. При работе с sqlite обнаружил ошибку. Как оказалось, если перед функцией длинный комментарий, то при попытке показать этот комментарий при наведении мышкой на имя функции по месту вызова, VS намертво зависает. По результату эксперимента для экрана 1440x900 допустим комментарий в 58 строк. Ниже приведён код, если навести мышкой на вызов func1() в main(), то всё зависнет. Что делать? Как обойти эту проблему?

```
 #include <iostream>

/*
** CAPI3REF: One-Step Query Execution Interface
** METHOD: sqlite3
**
** The sqlite3_exec() interface is a convenience wrapper around
** [sqlite3_prepare_v2()], [sqlite3_step()], and [sqlite3_finalize()],
** that allows an application to run multiple statements of SQL
** without having to use a lot of C code.
**
** ^The sqlite3_exec() interface runs zero or more UTF-8 encoded,
** semicolon-separate SQL statements passed into its 2nd argument,
** in the context of the [database connection] passed in as its 1st
** argument.  ^If the callback function of the 3rd argument to
** sqlite3_exec() is not NULL, then it is invoked for each result row
** coming out of the evaluated SQL statements.  ^The 4th argument to
** sqlite3_exec() is relayed through to the 1st argument of each
** callback invocation.  ^If the callback pointer to sqlite3_exec()
** is NULL, then no callback is ever invoked and result rows are
** ignored.
**
** ^If an error occurs while evaluating the SQL statements passed into
** sqlite3_exec(), then execution of the current statement stops and
** subsequent statements are skipped.  ^If the 5th parameter to sqlite3_exec()
** is not NULL then any error message is written into memory obtained
** from [sqlite3_malloc()] and passed back through the 5th parameter.
** To avoid memory leaks, the application should invoke [sqlite3_free()]
** on error message strings returned through the 5th parameter of
** sqlite3_exec() after the error message string is no longer needed.
** ^If the 5th parameter to sqlite3_exec() is not NULL and no errors
** occur, then sqlite3_exec() sets the pointer in its 5th parameter to
** NULL before returning.
**
** ^If an sqlite3_exec() callback returns non-zero, the sqlite3_exec()
** routine returns SQLITE_ABORT without invoking the callback again and
** without running any subsequent SQL statements.
**
** ^The 2nd argument to the sqlite3_exec() callback function is the
** number of columns in the result.  ^The 3rd argument to the sqlite3_exec()
** callback is an array of pointers to strings obtained as if from
** [sqlite3_column_text()], one for each column.  ^If an element of a
** result row is NULL then the corresponding string pointer for the
** sqlite3_exec() callback is a NULL pointer.  ^The 4th argument to the
** sqlite3_exec() callback is an array of pointers to strings where each
** entry represents the name of corresponding result column as obtained
** from [sqlite3_column_name()].
**
** ^If the 2nd parameter to sqlite3_exec() is a NULL pointer, a pointer
** to an empty string, or a pointer that contains only whitespace and/or
** SQL comments, then no SQL statements are evaluated and the database
** is not changed.
**
** Restrictions:
**
** <ul>
** <li> The application must ensure that the 1st parameter to sqlite3_exec()
**      is a valid and open [database connection].
** <li> The application must not close the [database connection] specified by
**      the 1st parameter to sqlite3_exec() while sqlite3_exec() is running.
** <li> The application must not modify the SQL statement text passed into
**      the 2nd parameter of sqlite3_exec() while sqlite3_exec() is running.
** </ul>
*/
void func1()
{

}

int main() 
{
    func1();
}
```

Comment: В VS2019 такая проблема не воспроизводится. Так что имеет смысл обновиться.

Comment: @user7860670, 
1. Какая редакция у вас?
2. Разрешение монитора такое же? Если по высоте больше, то имеет смысл добавить ещё строк, чтобы проверить.

Comment: Дома - Community.

Comment: @user7860670, а разрешение экрана какое?

Comment: 2 x 3840 × 2160

Comment: @user7860670, можете увеличить длину комментария в 3 раза и проверить поведение студии?

Comment: Я уже попробовал в 10 раз увеличить, но это ни на что не влияет. Когда коментарий длинный, то показываются только первые строк 10, а когда очень длинный, во всплывающей подсказке он не показывается. Но ничего не виснет.